# Hide or Dispose Form

Tags: c#, winforms, hide, dispose

I have a `MainForm`, from the `MainForm` i call the `ConfirmationForm`,

```
using (var f = new ConfirmationForm())
                f.ShowDialog();
```

Then in the `ConfirmationForm`, i want to show the another `UsersListForm`

```
if (ConfirmSuccess)
{
this.Hide; //or this.Close
using (var f = new UsersListForm())
f.ShowDialog();
}
```

Now, when the ConfirmSuccess is equal to true the `MainForm` will `Hide` or `Close` too. 
How to prevent that the `MainForm` will not to `Hide` or `Close`? any idea? Thanks in advance.


**UPDATE:** My problem is solve. I call first the `UsersListForm` and from the load event of `UsersListForm` I call the ConfirmationForm then I use `DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK` and everythings is fine now :)

Comment: show the entire function of MainForm wherein you show the ConfirmationForm.

Comment: You are using a using(){} after your last statement in the using it will dispose your f is this what you want or not?

Comment: its just a click event
 `private void usersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var f = new ConfirmationForm())
                f.ShowDialog();
        }`

Comment: sir @Jordy, even we will not use the `using(){}` my problem still happen.

Comment: but i want to Hide or Close the ConfirmationForm before the UserListForm will open :)

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to request user confirmation before opening the MainForm, the best way to do this would include you call and confirmation form after creating it and call MainForm.
If your intention is to seek confirmation at the beginning of the application, place the call ConfirmationForm within the Program class before the Application.Run (new MainForm ());

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        ConfirmationForm confForm = new ConfirmationForm();
        confForm.ShowDialog();
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

But if the intention is to request verification within the application in a separate call point, you should call the ConfirmationForm with ShowDialog and after that call the desired form.

But if your intention really is to verify the request with the open form, and hiding it, you can use the DialogResult property of ConfirmationForm to return the success or failure of the validation by comparing (`ConfirmationForm.ShowDialog () == DialogResult.OK`). See [this example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816145)

Comment: actually, i already use this trick from LoginForm to MainForm.
then i applied your suggestion the ConfirmationForm is still open.